# Anyone aware of a simple example of a Netty HTTP server which supports persistent HTTP connections?

Tags: http, netty

Can anyone provide an example of a simple HTTP server implemented using Netty, that supports persistent HTTP connections.

In other words, it won't close the connection until the client closes it, and can receive additional HTTP requests over the same connection?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is exactly one of the things their [sample http code](http://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/example/http/snoop/package-summary.html) demonstrates.

Comment: https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http